# Expanding out a summation with square root

Tags: calculus, summation

I was reviewing some summation and I noticed I was unable to do this question without expanding it out.

The summation:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{5} \sqrt{3 + \tfrac{1}{10}k}\cdot \tfrac{1}{10}.
$$
Sorry if its a trivial question, my first step was to bring the 1/10 in front of the summation. That leaves me with $\tfrac{1}{10} \sum \sqrt{3 + \tfrac{1}{10}k}\,$. I see there is a $k$ in there which makes me believe I will be able to use the sum formula for $k$ which is $n(n+1)/2$. I just can't seem to get their.

Comment: *there${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Here's a mathjax tutorial:https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: "*I see their[sic] is a $k$ in their[sic] which makes me believe I will be able to use the sum formula for $k$ which is $(n(n+1))/2$*"  Nope... pretty sure you can't.  Even a simpler sum of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^5\sqrt{k}$ will not have anything to do with the result you refer to, and more interestingly cannot easily be combined.  $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ for example has no cleaner way to write.  Given the small length of the summation, I expect the goal of the exercise was simply to see if you understand what summations are in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but unfortunately, you are going to have to expand it. There is no general closed-form formula for
$$H_n^{(-1/2)}=\sum_{x=1}^n\sqrt x$$
...which is very disappointing.

Comment: Reading this, [I am a sad panda now](https://weneedfun.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Sad-Memes-12.jpg)

Comment: Ohhh makes sense why I couldn't do it. Thank You very much!, just a question, but in general when a square root is involved is the summation pretty much stuck to its form and has to be manually expanded?

Comment: Yeah, usually... unless it telescopes. For example,
$$\sum_{x=0}^n \sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{n+1}$$

Comment: @JaideepKhare :(

Comment: Makes sense, I was just about to start telescoping series!

Comment: There is no *elementary* or *polynomial* closed form for that sum. But $$\sum_{x=1}^n\sqrt x = \zeta(-\frac{1}{2})+ \frac{2}{3}\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j \binom{3/2}{j} B_j \cdot n^{3/2-j}$$ with $\zeta$ the Riemann zeta function and $B_j$ the Bernoulli numbers. Check how close already the first few terms $\zeta(-\frac{1}{2}) + \frac{2}{3}n^{3/2}+ \frac{1}{2}n^{1/2}+\frac{1}{24}n^{-1/2} -\frac{1}{1920} n^{-5/2}$ approximate $\sum_{x=1}^n\sqrt x$.